Firebase unity Desktop build Beta Feature
I wanted to integrate firebase firestore to my Pc build when I noticed, that its not possible.
After I found out about this beta feature, which works on PC builds.
The problem is that it says:

Caution: Firebase Unity SDK desktop support is a beta feature. This feature is intended only for workflows during the development of your game, not for publicly shipping code.

What would happen now, if I would sell the project with it?
Would I get banned or is this just a recommendation?

you'd need to read the fineprint, but chances are it would be unlicensed

the meaning of this is simply that there is no guarantee of continued functionality or support from us if you release this.

So I am allowed to sell it?

I am unqualified to provide a legal interpretation of the licensing.
Back to your initial question though: all the beta designation means is what I stated above. The licensing question is different.
